# jquery ui accordion in mobile app

Tags: jquery, user-interface, accordion

I have a jquery ui accordion in a mobile app with almost 4 to 5 content panels in it. The last panel of accordion has a div with submit button and 2 text field. On clicking the textbox the keyboard pops up. After entering values in the text field using the keyboard and then on click of the submit button inside the panel causes the current active accordion panel to close and activate another accordion content panel which is not desired. Can anyone help me to find a way out to stop the closing of the active panel while clicking a button inside the panel.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td><td>col2</td><td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- row containing accordion which is loaded 
         dynamically on click of the above row-->
    <tr>
        <td colspan=3>
            <div id='accordion'>
                <div><h3>Heading1</h3></div>
                <div> Content1</div>
                <div><h3>Heading2</h3></div>
                <div> Content2</div>
                <div><h3>Heading3</h3></div>
                <div> Content3</div>
                <div><h3>Heading4</h3></div>
                <div> Content4</div>
                <div><h3>Heading5</h3></div>
                <div><!-- the div with submit button comes here -->
                    <div><input type="text" name="txt1"></div>
                    <div><input type="text" name="txt2"></div>
                    <div><input type="button" value="Submit"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script>
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,     
        heightStyle: "content"    
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Mind posting your markup?

Comment: you mean posting my question. Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: I meant post codes you have tried.

Comment: Kishore actually it's little messy and it's done using backbone.

Comment: Oh sorry for that. How could we help you.

Comment: Kishore I have added a sample . Please check it

Comment: event.stopPropagation() fixed it